# UICollectionView items in attribute navigator not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Items in attribute navigator(IB) for editing number of cell is not showing

[image]

It has to show like below image

[image]

And My XIB is

[image]

so  i am not able to see and custom the cell on CollectionView itself.

Comment: @Aman Can i get a minimal debug repo? It will be easier to know what is reason of your problem. Because of XCode or your project

Comment: I have  been trying to add UICollecltionView inside UIView in IB and i need to custom the cell inside the collection view. But it works like the above.

Comment: can you show full of storyboard?

Comment: It is Xib not storyboard

Comment: Ok show me the xib

Comment: added XIB just have a look

Answer (score 0):

In Collection View there is items not Cell. So when you increase number of items it'll increase cells in UICollectionView.

Comment: Did u understand my question? Yes that i know here items means UIcollectionviewcell but whatever it is not showing.what i have to do for showing items in atribute navigator?

Comment: Yeah, I got your question now,Are you using UICollectionView class or any other custom or library of UICollection view?

Comment: UICollectionView only

Comment: Try restarting your XCode or reAdding collection view in New ViewController, I think, that should be bug of XCode.